# Arduino software won't open in Mac OSX 10.10.1

Tags: arduino-ide, mac-os

I am having trouble opening the Arduino software on my mac, since I have updated Java to version 8 the Arduino software won't open. It does not give an error just closes instantly.

I have tried getting the newest version of the Arduino.cc site but no change.

Can anyone tell me how to open Arduino using an older version of Java?

Comment: Perhaps this should go on the Arduino Stack Exchange?

Comment: There are two versions available. One for java 6 and one for java 7. Did you try both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install the Apple version of Java (6): http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

If you need Java 8 SDK for some reason, the two can coexist because the Arduino IDE will explicitly ask for the (Apple Version) of Java 1.6 using 'JavaApplicationStub':

```
$ ./JavaApplicationStub
[JavaAppLauncher] Requested [1.5*], launching in [1.6] instead.
Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
```

Note however that if you have both Apple Java and Oracle installed, running 'java' or 'javac' form the command line will run the Oracle version.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
```

If you need to switch the 'command line' version, change the symlinks in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
```

'JavaApplicationStub' will use the Apple version located in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java.

As such, 'normal' java programs will generally use the Oracle version, while applications running in your browser or using JavaApplicationStub explicitly (like Arduino) will use the 'Apple' version.

Comment: Yeah that works sweet did have to open terminal to the Contents/MacOS of the Arduino app before JavaApplicationStub worked cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked on the apple icon => about this Mac => software update => Mac Sierra update.

now to get the USB port to work

numbatmark